# Create IconicTile without leaving the app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I define an IconicTile and and create it as such:

```
ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?id=Iconic", UriKind.Relative), icontile, true);
```

The app closes and the user gets to the start-screen, where the live-tile got just pinned.

How could I achieve the same effect, without leaving the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can't (create a Start screen tile without the user seeing what your app is doing).

Comment: Once I made it, can I update it that at least? (Without going out from the app?)

Comment: Sure - as long as the user hasn't removed it from the start screen.